# Regex to find html comment but not ie only comment

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I want to match valid HTML comment only using regex.
I have seen many questions on stackoverflow but no one answer this.
**Patterns allowed to match**

```
<!-- some comments 1 -->
<!-- 1.91 -->
<!--
//-->
<!-- -->
```

But not these IE-only comments

```
<!--[if IE]> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->  <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]> <![endif]-->
```

What I think that it can be done by taking help of '[' if it is found as first character after `<!--` it returns false.
any way you can give your own solution.
for php only to use preg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't recommend you do this using regex, but if you insist, here is a basic regular expression: http://regex101.com/r/wI2kF7

With anchor tags: http://regex101.com/r/tC9xH4

Good luck.

Comment: This is really great only one error. thanks i've to look further to make it perfect working.

Comment: What is the error? Nvm, just saw it. Thats why you should not use regex to parse html.

Comment: `<!-->  <!--<![endif]-->` mating this thing

Comment: this look's fine to me. But a last help there is a multi line comment. Ignore that only use single line comments. `<!--
//-->` remove this.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regular expression? Use a [DOMXPath query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) like the following

```
'//comment()[not(starts-with(., "[if") or . = "<![endif]")]'
```

See http://codepad.viper-7.com/Yzs5zq for a working example.

Comment: well using regex because pattern can be infinite. I too want to use this. but can't due to many reasons.

Comment: @BasicBridge You'll have to elaborate. What do you mean by *pattern can be infinite*? What are the reasons preventing you from using a DOM parser?

Comment: @BasicBridge Could you please explain your comment?

Comment: ya sure. well I have to distribute something and can't use any other material even it's open source DOM parser like phpdom can't use it.
Have to write everything of own. It's part of my project. I know you are right but i'm help less.

Comment: @BasicBridge PHP's DOM library is part of the standard build. Did you even look at my example?